# Making image fade in in reference to a different moving image

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my code, I am attempting to make one image `fadeIn()` next to another no matter what position on the screen the movable image is in (it is an image that can be controlled with arrow keys). When I try to move the movable image across the screen and spawn the other with the spacebar, the other image does not spawn next to it in such a way that I wish it would. I don't know if my problem is with my style code or with my jQuery.

Please help as soon as possible.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#poop').hide()


$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        case 37:
            $('#ballmer').animate({left: "-=50px"}, 'fast');
        break;
        case 38:
            $('#ballmer').animate({top: "-=50px"}, 'fast');
        break;
        case 39:
            $('#ballmer').animate({left: "+=50px"}, 'fast');
        break;
        case 40:
            $('#ballmer').animate({top: "+=50px"}, 'fast');
        break;
        case 32:
            $('#poop').fadeIn('fast')
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#ballmer{
width:200px;
position:absolute;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
border-radius:5px;
}

#poop{
position:relative;
overflow:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery for manipulating the element within the `case 32`:

#### **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WfXf5/3/)**

#### jQuery + Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#poop').hide()


    $(document).keydown(function (key) {
        switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        case 37:
            $('#ballmer').animate({
                left: "-=50px"
            }, 'fast');
            break;
        case 38:
            $('#ballmer').animate({
                top: "-=50px"
            }, 'fast');
            break;
        case 39:
            $('#ballmer').animate({
                left: "+=50px"
            }, 'fast');
            break;
        case 40:
            $('#ballmer').animate({
                top: "+=50px"
            }, 'fast');
            break;
        case 32:
            $('#poop').fadeIn('fast');   
            var ball = $("#ballmer");
            var ballmer_top = ball.css("top"); // ballmer's top offset
            // Poop's left offset = ballmer's left offset - width
            var ballmer_left = subPx(ball.css("left"), ball.width());                 
            $("#poop").css("top", ballmer_top); // set the values
            $("#poop").css("left", ballmer_left);
        }
    });
});

// Gets "300px" and "200", returns 300 - 200
function subPx(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a, 10) - b;
}
```

**Note**:

My code adds element to the left of the moving one, for right, change:

`var ballmer_left = subPx(ball.css("left"), ball.width())` to `var ballmer_left = addPx(ball.css("left"), ball.width())`

And add this at the end:

```
// Gets "300px" and "200", returns 300 + 200
function addPx(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a, 10) + b;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This really helps! But now I have another question; I'm implementing another movable character and he makes a different image appear next to him. I've tried copying the code and using different values so that it only affects the new character, but it still spawns that image in the same place. The one you helped me fix still works fine, but the other isn't working.

Comment: My code looks like this: case 65:$('#larry').animate({left: "-=50px"}, 'fast')break;case 83:$('#larry').animate({top:"+=50px"}, 'fast');break;case 87:$('#larry').animate({top:"-=50px"}, 'fast');break;
            case 68:
                $('#larry').animate({left:"+=50px"}, 'fast')
                break;case 69:$('#goldPoo').fadeIn('fast');var larr = $('#larry');var larry_top = larr.css('top');var larry_left = subPx2(larr.css('left'), larr.width());$('#goldPoo').css('top', larry_top);$('#goldPoo').css('left', larry_left)break;

Comment: @user3367090 [Fixed](http://jsbin.com/tejatagi/1/edit?output). Look for comments in the code.